# How to: auto resize featured image, blogger?

Tags: html, css, image, thumbnails, autoresize

Anyone know any code that auto resize only the featured image of the post ?

This is the code I've found that automatically resizes all images on blogger posts:

```
.post-body img {
    width: 180px!important;
    height: 110px!important;
}
```

But I only want to resize the first thumbnail of post.
Anyone know how?

Thanks!

Comment: As you are saying feature image, do it has any special class or id attached with it??

Answer (score 1):

**You could try:**

```
.post-body img:first-child {
    width: 180px !important;
    height: 110px !important;
}
```

That'll only apply the CSS rules to the first `img` inside of `.post-body`.

I wouldn't recommend getting into the habit of using `!important` on your styles, or you'll find it a real pain when you keep changing things. The more specific your CSS target is, the higher priority it has.

I'm not very familiar with Blogger, so I'm guessing you're not changing any markup, but just adding some custom CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
I tried it but didnt work :/